# Kibana 3 GeoJSON vs Kibana4 Geohash

Tags: elasticsearch, geojson, kibana, geohashing

I was testing Kibana 4 beta2 when I realized that it's not possible to use a tilemap with an index from kibana3.

With Kibana3 it's possible to put points on "Bettermap" using an array containin Long,Lat (GeoJson).

```
  "coordinates": [
    -50.6667,
    -32.99
  ]
```

Now Kibana4 uses elasticsearch's geohash.

Does anybody know how to use geojson on kibana4?
Is that possible to get a geohash from geojson?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the following mapping for your coordinates field:

```
"coordinates" : {
    "type" : "geo_point",
    "lat_lon" : true,
    "geohash" : true
 }
```

Now it will show up in the new tile map. I had to increase the precision slider bar for the location to be more "precise".

You may want to use doc_values, I am not sure the significance of that:

```
"coordinates" : {
    "type" : "geo_point",
    "lat_lon" : true,
    "geohash" : true,
    "index": "not_analyzed",
    "doc_values": true
 }
```